# Do finite groups act admissibly on separated schemes of finite type over k

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-actions, projective-space

**Background:** Recall from SGAI that a group $G$ acts admissibly on a scheme $X$ if the quotient $X \to X/G$ exists and is an affine morphism of schemes. This is the case if and only if every orbit of $G$ (meaning every set of the form $Gx$, with $x \in X$) is contained in an affine open subset of $X$.
By graded prime avoidance it follows that this is the case for quasi-projective schemes, and more generally by EGA II Corollary 4.5.4 this is satisfied if $X$ has an ample invertible sheaf.

**My question:**  Suppose that $X$ is a separated scheme of finite type over a field $k$ (not necessarily algebraically closed). Does any finite group $G$ act admissibly on $X$? Clearly this will be true if $X$ has a locally closed embedding into projective space, can we add some assumptions on $X$ that yields the aforementioned locally closed embedding?

Comment: Certainly there are varieties that are not projective, so the answer to the last question is definitely no.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a variety which are not quasiprojective apart from pathologies like spectrums of fields?

Comment: But thanks I edited my question, to make it more precise.

Comment: The two examples I can think of offhand are a (necessarily) complete singular surface and a smooth threefold. Both of these are mentioned in Hartshorne's book. There's also an [article by Nagata](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250777007) which might be hard to read.